# Assigning true value to float

Tags: c++, floating-point, boolean, implicit-conversion

Is it guaranteed that

- assigning true to a float variable results in 1.0f
- assigning false to a float variable results in 0.0f
- testing the above variable for truth returns as expected (true and false respectively?)

Comment: And I can't seem to find a warning level at which the compiler complains about assignments like this. So, you're good. But yes, why?

Comment: I don't think a mere 'why' expresses deeply enough the depth of astonishment that should be evoked by this question. There are no circumstances I can imagine where it would be desirable to rely on any of those behaviours. If you need to ask you shouldn't be relying. fpv = boolv ? 1.0 : 0.0 is clear enough

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, why C++11 -> C++?

Comment: Because this is about C++, and not at all specific to the latest revision.

Comment: @Vorac: tags serve two purposes. (1) to tell answerers what you're asking about, (2) to help people searching the site in future. In the long run (2) is far more important, and for this question the answer is the same either way (although you didn't know that when you asked). Of course, on the same basis that it was changed from C++11 to C++, we could add C and Java to the list of things for which the answer is the same. So a certain restraint is required, but the C++ tag is pretty similar to the C++11 tag. Also C++11 technically is the current version of C++, albeit nobody has implemented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For the first two, 4.9/2 ("Floating-integral conversions"):

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to one.

For the last one, 4.12/1 ("Boolean conversions"):

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

Plus I suppose you need to know that it's guaranteed zero and one can be represented as values of `float`. That's implied by the above (else the conversion could not behave as described), but I'm not sure if and where it's explicitly stated which integer values are required to be exactly representable in `float`.

Quotations are from N3337, which is almost exactly C++11. The tags have since changed to "C++" rather than "C++11" -- the rules in C++03 are the same but the wording and paragraph numbers might be different.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use them. Just for your information, the situation has to do with template parameters.

Comment: Considering that `0` and `1` are the identity elements of `+` and `*` respectivel, I'd expect that they at least are representable!

Comment: @MSalters: you'd hope so. Maybe I shouldn't write down every idle thought that occurs to me while answering a question!

Comment: @SteveJessop Whether an exact representation of `0.0` and `1.0` is required is a good question.  I'd be surprised if there was any wording in the standard to that effect, but probably because the idea that they might not have an exact representation didn't occur to anyone.  (In practice, every representation I've ever heard of can exactly represent integers whose absolute value is less than some fairly large maximum.)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the standard (N3290), sect 4.5 para 6, 7:

> [...] A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true`
>   becoming one. These conversions are called *integral promotions*.

sect 4.9 para 2:

> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating
>   point type. The result is exact if possible. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can
>   be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly, it is an implementation-defined choice of either
>   the next lower or higher representable value.

(both zero and one can be represented exactly (without loss) as floats if they follow IEEE 754 standard.)

Comment: Btw, N3290 is the final draft that the committee voted on. N3337 incorporates editorial changes prior to the publishing of the actual standard. I'm not sure what official ISO process, other than the risk of being tarred and feathered, prevents the editor from re-introducing `export` templates during editing.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not as sure as I once was (these things can change), but I think that once the final draft has been voted, the only editorial changes allows are spelling and grammatical corrections.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm just curious whether there's actually a process by which a committee member or an ISO member-organization could, in principle, object to an edit on the basis that it is too big. I've seen one case so far where the wording in N3337 was (IMO) substantially clearer, there was a potential ambiguity in N3290 that was removed. Can't remember what it was about, but there was a dodgy use of a semi-colon in the earlier version. The fix was to split into two sentences, which required adding words, and the person I was arguing with had read the meaning that was ruled out by the fix.

Comment: ... so if some member organization had (bizarrely) only approved the draft because they had also read the meaning that was ruled out, then they'd have a grievance!

Comment: @SteveJessop There is (or was, at least, when I was active with the French standards body) an extensive period of comments between the vote of the "committee draft" and the final draft.  Formally, no real changes are supposed to occur in this period, only clarifications.  I guess if some member body did disagree as to whether something was a clarification or a change, they could complain to ISO; I've never heard of such a case, however.